# How do I go back a directory in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, directory, handler

I had this problem with my discord bot. Basically, here is my file structure:

```
(bot)
main.js
./extra
./commands
./events
(extra)
config.json
cmdhandle.js
(commands)
-
(events)
message.js
```

Okay so in the () we have directories. Now the problem is with `cmdhandle.js`. That is the command handler. Now there I want some line to go back a directory, because `cmdhandle.js` is in `./extra` and I want so it would be in the `bot` directory. Is there a way to go back one directory like in batch `cd..`? And just defining `../commands` or something for the command handler won't work for me. I need it to be just a single function. I've been trying to use `fs.readdir` but I don't understand much on how to do it.

Edit:
Okay, now what I wanted is basically to do this like in Batch `cd..` because my command handler, if I try to just use `../commands` or like `../events` it just wouldn't work, and output an error, though the bot would start. I feel like there is an issue where it is going back a directory each time you do `../`, but I am just confused about what is my command handler doing, honestly. Might post a question to make a proper command handler later.

Edit 2:
Okay, I was asked for bot code, here is the `cmdhandle.js`:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Enmap = require('enmap')
const fs = require('fs')
const client = new Discord.Client();
fs.readdir("../", () => {
});
fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`)
    let eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
  });
});

client.commands = new Enmap();

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
    let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
    console.log(`Attempting to load command ${commandName}`);
    client.commands.set(commandName, props);
  });
});
```

Okay, and here is the `main.js`:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./extra/config.json')
const varbex = require('./extra/extravars.json')
const cmdh = require('./extra/cmdhandle.js')
eval(varbex) 
eval(cmdh)

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("The bot has connected. Connected with the tag " + client.user.tag)
});
client.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content.type === 'file') {
        console.log(msg.author.tag + ": [File sent]")
    } else console.log(msg.author.tag + ": " + msg.content)
});
client.login(config.token)
```

Oh, by the way, didn't mention there is a special file with extra variables in the `./extra` folder.
Edit 3:
Error I got:

```
Hello there!
BotNoob is starting...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './events/message.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\mantv\OneDrive\Stalinis kompiuteris\Coding\BotNoob\extra\cmdhandle.js
- C:\Users\mantv\OneDrive\Stalinis kompiuteris\Coding\BotNoob\main.js
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)[39m
[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)[39m
[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)[39m
    at C:\Users\mantv\OneDrive\Stalinis kompiuteris\Coding\BotNoob\extra\cmdhandle.js:10:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\mantv\OneDrive\Stalinis kompiuteris\Coding\BotNoob\extra\cmdhandle.js:9:9
[90m    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:146:23)[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: [
    [32m'C:\\Users\\mantv\\OneDrive\\Stalinis kompiuteris\\Coding\\BotNoob\\extra\\cmdhandle.js'[39m,
    [32m'C:\\Users\\mantv\\OneDrive\\Stalinis kompiuteris\\Coding\\BotNoob\\main.js'[39m
  ]
}
BotNoob just went down. Did we crash, or did we shutdown? Click anything to start again!
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. You can go back a directory with `../` if you need to. Read the fs documentation if you want to understand it

Comment: If it's the same syntax as Nodejs you can use things like `path.resolve( __dirname + "../" )`

Comment: @Mikkel I will edit the post so it's a little easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

**I understand what you are trying to do**

You can use `../(file)` or using the `__dirname + (file)`.
EG:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Enmap = require('enmap')
const fs = require('fs')
const client = new Discord.Client();
fs.readdir("../", () => {
});
fs.readdir(__dirname + "/events/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`)
    let eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
  });
});

client.commands = new Enmap();

fs.readdir(__dirname + "/commands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
    let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
    console.log(`Attempting to load command ${commandName}`);
    client.commands.set(commandName, props);
  });
});
```

If you could attach your code to your answer I would be more than happy to edit it for you.

Edit: Can you show the error?

Comment: Hold up, about to post the code of the cmdhandle.js, and if you need code for main.js, I will post that aswell! Oh, and don't worry, the bot token is in a seperate file and I won't just give it away.

Comment: I won't need the `main.js` since the issue is in cmdhandle.js

Comment: Try removing the `/` on `events` and `commands`, it will then be `./commands` and `./events`

Comment: I am confused about what you want me to do, @Erik.

Comment: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\mantv\OneDrive\Stalinis kompiuteris\Coding\BotNoob\extra\events'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\mantv\\OneDrive\\Stalinis kompiuteris\\Coding\\BotNoob\\extra\\events'
}
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\mantv\OneDrive\Stalinis kompiuteris\Coding\BotNoob\extra\commands'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\mantv\\OneDrive\\Stalinis kompiuteris\\Coding\\BotNoob\\extra\\commands'
}

Comment: Huh,that’s werid. It should work though.I have edited my answer, try again with that code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208627/discussion-between-mantvydas-virsilas-and-erik).